# Trim both leading and trailing parts of a string with different characters

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

My Data Field In A Postgres Table Contains:

```
{"people":0}
```

I want to only display the number character zero as a result.

I tried using the [trim function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) from the Postgres manual but that seems to only trim both leading and trailing characters when they are the same.

How could I go about trimming the above data field to simply return:

```
0
```

I tried doing

```
trim(leading '{"people":' from jobs.data)
```

But that simply results in:

```
0}
```

Comment: Is it a json field ?

Comment: Its a text field, that's all I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can be done with [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
 select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('{"people":100}', '(.*):',''), '}','');
```